# How to stop two runables with one button?

Tags: java, android, freeze, runnable

I am having an issure trying to stop both of my runnables with one stop button, i can stop just one of the two just fine but as soon as i try to stop both my app freezes when the button is pressed on my phone, here is my code so far:

```
    if(go != 1){
        go = 1;
    final Timer t =new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    if(DHPDPS==0){
                        money = (DPPS+Reserve);
                        Reserve = (money);
                        String end = String.format("%1f", money);
                        t1.setText("$" + end);
                    }else if(counter > DHPDPS && DOTPPS != 0 && DHPDPS != 0){
                        money = (DOTPPS+Reserve);
                        Reserve = (money);
                        String end = String.format("%1f", money);
                        t1.setText("$" + end);
                    } else{

                        money = (DPPS+Reserve);
                        Reserve = (money);
                        String end = String.format("%1f", money);
                        t1.setText("$" + end);
                    }
                    //Place your stopping condition over here. Its important to have a stopping condition or it will go in an infinite loop. 
                    counter++;

                    // Display pay per second
                    if(counter <= DHPDPS || DHPDPS == 0){
                    t2.setText("Your pay per second is: $"+result);
                    }else{
                        t2.setText("Your pay per second is: $"+result2);
                    }
                }
            }); 
        }
    }, 20, 20);

 // Make countdown to overtime display
    final TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdown);
    countdown = (int)HPDPS;
    cd.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    int hours = (countdown/3600);
                    if(OTPPS != 0 && HPDPS != 0){
                            count.setText("Seconds Remaining to Overtime: " + countdown + "\nAbout " + hours + " Hours");
                            countdown--;
                        }
                }
            });
        }

    }, 1000, 1000);



    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockout);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(go == 1)
                go = 0;
            if (t != null)
                t.cancel();
            // if (cd != null)  // This condition Freezes my phone when activated?
            //  cd.cancel();
            }
    });

    } 

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what the problem was, it turned out to be a really simple fix,
Here is my original code byte:

```
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockout);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(go == 1)
            go = 0;
        if (t != null)
            t.cancel();
        // if (cd != null)  // This condition Freezes my phone when activated?
        //  cd.cancel();
        }
```

Here is what i did to fix the problem:

```
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockout);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(go == 1)
                go = 0;
            if (t != null){
                t.cancel();
                cd.cancel();
            }
            }
```

It was extremely simple, just something i looked over i guess, Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void run() {
    while(running) {
         //your code for both runnables
    }
}

final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clockout);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(running) {
            running = false;
        }    
    }
});
```

With this code, your runnables will check if they should be running each loop, and if not, they will exit their `run()` and the thread will stop.

Comment: i am confused on what part of my code i put at "//your code for both runnables" From the first "@override" all the way to ",1000, 1000)" ?

Comment: Your runnables contain both a `run()` method. In that run method, your  top code should contain a `while(running){ }`.

Comment: @Hockeyman271: He means that you should put a loop like that inside both your `Runnable`s.

Comment: these suggestions seem off to me, you're really trying to cancel a TimerTask in your button click. I don't see where timer "cd" is instantiated. I do recommend nulling out your timer after cancel.

Comment: So i have to declare "running"? like private static boolene running; rite?

Comment: Correct. But don't do it static.

Comment: @tolgap what should it be instead of static?

Comment: There is no looping operation inside your Runnable, you've written code that is based on Timer operations.  This concept of a static boolean flag won't help.

Comment: @CSmith what do you suggest i do? can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Create a `boolean` variable which will be set to `true` in the beginning...

**2.** Use this variable in both the `runnables` like ... `while (isOk)`

**3.** On the click of the button, make this `boolean` variable as `false`, and **both the runnnable
       will cease to exists...**